# GTK background-full-height dosn't work

Tags: c, background, textview, gtk, height

I need your help, I'm trying to set background color on whole length of TextView.
I'm trying to do it with this declaration:

```
gtk_text_buffer_create_tag(buffer, "white_bg", "background-full-height", TRUE, "background", "white","foreground", "blue", NULL);
```

And when I set text with:

```
  gtk_text_buffer_insert_with_tags_by_name(buffer, &iter,"SAMPLE TEXT", -1, "white_bg", "left",  NULL);
```

It sets blue font, white background but it doesn't set white bg on whole length, only under text.

Can You help me to figure out what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is by design: when you customize a tag, it influences the *text* with that tag. To modify the background of the whole widget, use [`gtk_widget_modify_bg`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-modify-bg). For example (untested):

```
GdkColor white;
gdk_color_parse("white", &white);
gtk_widget_modify_bg(textview, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &white);
```

Note that the documentation claims that `gtk_widget_modify_bg` is deprecated in favor of `gtk_widget_override_background_color`, which is in turn deprecated in favor of *an application-specific `GtkStyleProvider` and a CSS style class* - without a clear example of how to do so.

Comment: You use the GtkStyleProvider subclass GtkCssProvider to inject custom CSS Into a GtkStyleContext (either the current widget's or the default screen's). The GtkStyleContext documentation *should* tell you about how to specify the CSS. This is all for GTK+ 3; if you need GTK+ 2 then I wouldn't know.